# Upgrade SOLR 6.0 to 6.2

Tags: solr

I've got a SOLR 6.0 instance on Windows. Not a cluster, a single server setup. I'd like to migrate to 6.2, the latest, because why not. There's an 600GB index that I don't want to lose.

Please, how? The guide at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Upgrading+Solr contains no guidance whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the Solr versions should be enough. The index format will be updated when the new segments are written, but 6.2 are able to read 6.0 indexes just fine. Unless you're bitten by the 6.1-thing about historical dates, installing the new Solr version and pointing in to your existing dataDir should work.

As always, testing it out somewhere else than production first is a good idea.

Comment: On Windows, where the whole SOLR, code and data and config, sits in one folder, which one is the dataDir?

Comment: Usually it's stored in data/ under the home directory of Solr (SOLR_HOME), but `<dataDir>` in solrconfig.xml can change that. Look for a directory named `data` under either $SOLR_HOME or under a directory named after your collection / core.

Comment: There's %SOLR_HOME%\server\solr\corename\data. But also conf. And I'm not sure where is the core list stored.

Comment: `conf` contains any setup for your core (schema, solrconfig, stopwords, etc), while the data dir contains the actual data (index files). You'll probably find a list of active cores (if you have more than one) in %SOLR_HOME%\server\solr